# Serial Port accessing code for linux platform

Tags: java, linux, serial-port, virtual-serial-port

I'm working on a project to communicate to the serial ports using Java. Do I need to have a device connected to serial port to test the following code?

```
Enumeration ports = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
while (ports.hasMoreElements()) {
    CommPortIdentifier port = (CommPortIdentifier) ports.nextElement();
    String type;
    switch (port.getPortType()) {
        case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL:
            type = "Parallel";
            break;
        case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL:
            type = "Serial";
            break;
        default: /// Shouldn't happen
            type = "Unknown";
            break;
    }
    System.out.println(port.getName() + ": " + type);
}
```

Any solution to make this code working. Currently I'm getting an error as follows.(without attaching any device to serial port.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.comm.SunrayInfo.isSessionActive()Z
        at com.sun.comm.SunrayInfo.isSessionActive(Native Method)
        at com.sun.comm.Portmapping.registerCommPorts(Portmapping.java:155)
        at com.sun.comm.Portmapping.refreshPortDatabase(Portmapping.java:100)
        at javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:138)
        at PortTest.main(PortTest.java:9)
Java Result: 1
```

I've configured comm with jre. I've followed [this](http://www.agaveblue.org/howtos/Comm_How-To.shtml) blog to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit struggles, I got the code running.

One mistake I made was using `RxTx 2.2` library for Fedora 13. It uses 2.2 version of `libSerial` and `libParellal` files and 2.1 `RxTxComm` jar file. When I removed it and used `RxTx2.1` I got an error like following.

```
gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver cannot be cast to javax.comm.CommDriver
```

While checking for this error, I found the second mistake I made and solution for the above problem. I was using RxTx Driver with java Comm API. Actually the required class files in Java Comm API is already available in the RxTx library with in "`gnu.io`" package.

So I changed all the `javax.comm.*` packages to `gnu.io.*`. Now I can run the application without any error.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the native libraries required. The line above the error lines you posted is telling you that.

You need to install the javax.comm extention - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html

If you're using windows, it's no longer supported or available from Sun/Oracle. You may be able to find an older version on the net or someone else porting it.

Comment: http://www.agaveblue.org/howtos/Comm_How-To.shtml     I'm following this post to configure the system.

Comment: I'm little confused with connection to serial port. At present there is no device attached to my serial ports. Is this because of it. Can we create a virtual serial port in linux. I'm using fedora OS.

Comment: That's horribly out of date, but as long as you downloaded the newest Linux version, you at least have the correct files. The error you're getting means that java can't find the `.so` (native library) files. You can check your library path with `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));` - the `.so` files need to be in one of those.